# Passing Element Count and Indices Into forEach Operation of Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a simple **Stream** operation like this:

```
interactionList.stream().forEach(interaction -> process(interaction));
```

and then a process method

```
private void process(Interaction interaction) {
    doSomething(interaction);
}
```

I want to change my process function so that it can use the total number of elements and the index of the currently processed one as in this updated version

```
private void process(Interaction interaction, int index, int totalCount) {
    doSomething(interaction, int index, int totalCount);
}
```

Is there a way to simply pass these arguments into the **lambda expression** of `forEach` method by collecting them from the **same stream without using extra prior operations**? Looking for something like this:

```
interactionList.stream().forEach(interaction -> process(interaction, stream.index, stream.count));
```

I am just asking this out of curiosity so please don't provide any alternative methods, I already implemented it by using collectors.

Comment: No, something like that is not possible. If you want to access an index, use a regular for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using extra prior operations"? I would use an `IntStream` of the list's indices. Does that count as "extra prior operations"?

Comment: @Amongalen mhm sad but anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper like counting the number of elements before using the stream. I want to get the count inside the same lambda operation, just for clarity.

Comment: @CanBayar Does the `interactionList.size()` correspond to `totalCount` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `interactionList.size()` correspond to `totalCount`?

If yes, then you can try the approach below:

```
IntStream.range(0, interactionList.size())
         .forEachOrdered(index -> process(interactionList.get(index), index, interactionList.size()));
```

Comment: In the real code piece I had, I didn't actually have the list but directly had the stream. But since I give the list in the question, thanks haha. :)